# SwiftUI - Increment variable in a ForEach loop doesn't work for some reason

Tags: swift, swiftui

Please help. I have this in my `ContentView`:

```
func makeView() -> Text{
    self.index += 1 // add one to this variable
    return Text("App")//Return a view
}

ForEach(0..<imageArray.count){ row in
 HStack{
  ForEach(0..<PartyCollectionViewCell.column){ column in
      self.makeView() // Call the function in the content view
      PartyCollectionViewCell(cellImg: imageArray[index+1]!) 
      }         //update the cell
  }
}
```

I want to update my "index" variable in `PartyCollectionViewCell(celling:imageArray[index+1]!)` to add one to the `index` variable.

I even created func called makeview as seen below to update it but it doesn't work.

Comment: The logic of this snapshot is not clear for me. What is index? Why do you need to shift it? And what do you try to achieve here at all?

Comment: @Asperi index is just a global variable that I want to change its value inside the ForEach loop statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of increasing `index`, compute the index from the `row` and `column` indices.

If your array contains 8 images and you want 2 columns, then you will have `8/2 == 4` rows.  Your outer loop should loop over the number of rows which can be computed as `imageArray.count/PartyCollectionViewCell.column`.

Then the index of the image would be `row * PartyCollectionViewCell.column + column`.

```
func makeView() -> Text{
    return Text("App") //Return a view
}

ForEach(0..<(imageArray.count/PartyCollectionViewCell.column)) { row in
    HStack{
        ForEach(0..<PartyCollectionViewCell.column) { column in
            self.makeView() // Call the function in the content view
            PartyCollectionViewCell(cellImg: imageArray[row * PartyCollectionViewCell.column + column]!) 
        }         //update the cell
    }
}
// Handle partial row
if (imageArray.count % PartyCollectionViewCell.column > 0) {
    HStack {
        ForEach((imageArray.count/PartyCollectionViewCell.column)*PartyCollectionViewCell.column..<imageArray.count) { index in
            self.makeView()
            PartyCollectionViewCell(cellImg: imageArray[index]!) 
        }
        ForEach(0..<(PartyCollectionViewCell.column - imageArray.count % PartyCollectionViewCell.column)) { _ in
            EmptyView()
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: So my end goal is to using a scrollview that scrolls vertically. Loop through an array of images and place those image views in pairs of 2s side by side on the scrollview. So I have a PartyCollectionViewCell class that just puts the image onto the imageview

Comment: Right, so you're trying to send `imageArray[2]` to the first instance of PartyCollectionViewCell(cellImg:)` and `imageArray[3] to the next, and `imageArray[4]` to the next.  So assuming `PartyCollectionViewCell.column == 2`, then the calculation `row * PartyCollectionViewCell.column + column + 2]` gives increasing numbers.

Comment: yeah I just did that and im getting a nil when I do that

Comment: I put in `+ 2` because it seemed to match your math.  Do you need the index to start at `0`.  If so, remove the `+2`.

Comment: so this is my array : var imageArray : [Int: String] = [0:"kanye",1:"kelani",2:"trippie",3:"astro",4:"riri",5:"migos",6: "cindy",7:"cheesy"]. So I just need the code to take loop through this and pick 0 and 1 images and put in the first row. 2 and 3 in the second row. And so on and so forth. I don't really understand your math sorry

Comment: I updated the answer.  I misunderstood your outer loop.  It should be looping over the number of columns.  This math will work fine *if* you have enough images to give every row exactly 2.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreciate it. I'm just running into issues with this when my array count is odd instead of an even number like above

Comment: I added code (untested) to handle a partial row.  I haven't compiled it, but take a look and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with collections of images, I suggest you to use:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let data = (1...1000).map { "Item \($0)" }

    let columns = [
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 80))
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}
```

As wrote [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-position-views-in-a-grid-using-lazyvgrid-and-lazyhgrid). In the link you can find also a solution if you are workin with target iOS13